# JpaRepository save() creating new child objects instead of updating

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, gson

I am currently converting the below JSON into two java objects using GSON. The Company object contains an Accounts object in a one-to-one relationship.

JSON:

```
{
  "company_name": "ETHEREUM LTD",
  "accounts": {
    "next_made_up_to": "2018-11-30",
    "next_due": "2019-08-31"
  },
  "company_number": "11090535"
}
```

Company Object:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Accounts accounts;

    @NotNull
    @SerializedName("company_number")
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String companyNumber;

    @SerializedName("company_name")
    private String companyName;

    public Company() {}

    public Company(String companyNumber) {
        this.companyNumber = companyNumber;
    }
}
```

Accounts Object:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Accounts {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @SerializedName("next_due")
    private Date nextDue;

    @SerializedName("next_made_up_to")
    private Date nextMadeUpTo;
}
```

I have implemented a Spring Data JpaRepository to save these objects to my database.

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {
}
```

I have a method to update all Company objects in the database with new JSON information.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 50000)
public void updateAllCompanies() {
    System.out.println("Starting update!");
    for(Company company : companyRepository.findAll()) {
        Long companyId = company.getId();
        Long accountsId = null;
        if(company.getAccounts() != null) {
            accountsId = company.getAccounts().getId();
        }
        company = getCompany(company.getCompanyNumber());
        company.setId(companyId);
        if(accountsId != null) {
            company.getAccounts().setId(accountsId);
        }
        companyRepository.save(company);
    }
}
```

Unless I manually set the ids on both the parent and child object, these objects are created as new database entries rather than updating existing entries. Is there a better way of handling this than manually setting the ids in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unless I manually set the ids on both the parent and child object, these objects are created as new database entries rather than updating existing entries.

That is how every persistence provider works.

If the `@Id` field of an entity isn't marked to be auto-generated by the persistence provider or the database, then the presense of a null-value will trigger the provider to throw an exception.  However if the field is marked to be auto-generated by the provider or the database, it will skip the exception and treat the entity as a new instance that must be inserted.  Only under the existence of a value in the identifier field will trigger an update to an existing row.

> Is there a better way of handling this than manually setting the ids in Java?

That depends.

If the JSON payload can provide you with the id values, you can simply serialize those into the objects and the persistence process would work just like you manually assigning them.  This means entities that have identifier values will be updated, those without will be inserted.

If that isn't a plausible option, then you're going to need to assign them if you intend to use an `@Entity` to represent your `Accounts`.

I'm not sure if your `Accounts` entity is references by anything else in your data model.  But one thing to consider here is how powerful an `@ElementCollection` of embeddables could very easily solve your identifier problem too:

```
@Embeddable 
public class Accounts implements Serializable {
  private Date nextDue;
  private Date nextMadeUpTo;
  // implement proper equals/hashcode here
}

@Entity
public class Customer {
  // your normal things
  @ElementCollection
  private Set<Accounts> Accounts;
}
```

Now all you need to do is add whatever data your JSON gets into an `Accounts` and place it into the element-collection.  Hibernate will then take care of determining whether or not something needs to be removed or inserted for you by using a collection-table like the following:

```
CUSTOMER_ID | NEXT_DUE | NEXT_MADE_UP_TO
```

The proper using of `equals` / `hashCode` on the `Accounts` embeddable guarantees no duplicates, it also helps determine what is modified or not too.  The underlying collection-table now uses all fields of the embeddable + the `Customer` primary key as the table's primary key.  This avoids the problem with a surrogate primary key by using as the data as natural keys.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I wasn't aware of the embeddable annotation so will have to read into this more :)