# PUT makes POST instead of updating value in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I don't understand why, but whenever I do put operation in postman this method always creates new vehicle
**This is code for put mapping**

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public Vehicle updateVehicle(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody Vehicle vehicle){
    vehicle.setVehicleId(id);
    return vehicleRepository.saveAndFlush(vehicle);
}
```

**This is code for post mapping**

```
@PostMapping("")
public Vehicle newVehicle(@RequestBody Vehicle vehicle){
    return vehicleRepository.saveAndFlush(vehicle);
}
```

Comment: Your question is missing important details on the setup of your entity and repository.  You may need to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542958/jparepository-save-creating-new-child-objects-instead-of-updating) explaining possible reasons of creating a new object instead of updating existing one.

Comment: If this is JPA, your JPA provider tracks the detachedness state of the object separately from your `setId`. The proper way to handle this is to retrieve the object and copy the properties. (You don't need an explicit save call with JPA.) MapStruct's `update` handling can do most of this for you (make sure to remember to exclude the `id` field for copying), and you can just say `@PathVariable("id") Vehicle vehicle` and Spring will retrieve the entity for you.